# For "double layer" of dependent editable computed fields, why is the population of values incorrect?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

The full question is:
For 3 editable computed fields A, B, C. Where C depends on B, B depends on A. After editing A, edit C. how to ensure the saved value of C, is the final edit, and not the earlier computation resulting from editing A?

Editable compute field is of the form: 
fields.Integer(compute="funcA", store=True, inverse="inverse_funcA")

**Example:**

```
A = fields.Integer(store=True, compute='_compute_A', inverse='dummy_inverse')
B = fields.Integer(store=True, compute='_compute_B', inverse='dummy_inverse')
C = fields.Integer(store=True, compute='_compute_C', inverse='dummy_inverse')

@api.depends("A")
def _compute_B(self):
   self.B = A

@api.depends("B"):
def _compute_C(self):
   self.C = B

def dummy_inverse(self):
   return True
```

Problematic Scenario 1 (for a record, in form view): 
(1) Now, **I edit A**. This triggers recomputation of B and C. 
(2) I edit C. Displayed correctly.
(3) Save.
(4) **Problem**: the value of C, is NOT the value in (2), instead it is the value in (1).

Problematic Scenario 2 (for a record, in form view):
(1) Now, **I edit A**. This triggers recomputation of B and C.
(2) I edit B. This triggers recomputation of C.
(3) I edit C. (displayed correctly)
(4) Save.
(5) **SAME Problem**: the value of C, is NOT the value in (2), instead it is the value in (1).

---

Working scenario (for a record, in form view):
(1) **I edit B.** This triggers recomputation of C.
(2) I edit C. (displayed correctly)
(3) Save.
(4) C is saved **correctly**.

My question is, why is the value not correctly stored when there are "double layers" of dependent fields?
Is this a bug?

Thank you.